# mcmc vs the bootstrap

Tags: confidence-interval, markov-chain-montecarlo, credible-interval

What is more accurate, the mcmc derive 95% credible interval or the bootstrap derived 95% confidence interval? Can this be proved mathematically?

> the emphasis of the Bayesian approach is that one is only interested in choosing the optimal action under the actual observed data,
> whereas choosing the actual frequentist optimal decision rule, which is a function of all possible observations, is a much more difficult problem.

I mean, when I have the response variable Y, does this mean that bayesian technique should be used? I expect that mcmc credible interval is just as good as bootstrap 95% confidence interval. I do not see the rational for using credible interval over confidence interval. Is it because observations here relate to predictor variables; using these to get parameters is much more difficult than just using Y response data.

Here I used 95% interval as an example, but my question relates to the general properties of the two approach, especially since bootstrap can also be thought of as a bayesian approach "with a discrete (very)non informative prior, where the assumptions being made in the model is that the data is discrete":

The bootstrap and Markov chain Monte Carlo, Bradley Efron

updated 2021-11-06:
The bootstrap can be thought of a bayesian approach with non informative prior. Does it mean that mcmc approach is better when one has prior information about the model. But the above reference seems to highlight advantage of bootstrap approach.

In terms of definition of accurate here, I guess the appropriate criteria here would be coverage probability i.e. which approach gives a closer true coverage probability to the specified interval probability.

In terms of model, I would be talking about a situation where one could use a bayesian approach to model the parameters instead of a frequentist approach, hence, the bootstrap method could be thought of a non-informative prior bayesian approach. The assumption would be that there could be prior knowledge and that the distributions could be modelled as gaussian distributions, since law of large numbers are applied.

Comment: They address different problems. I don’t see how to compare them. What would it mean to you for one to outperform the other?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: what is your model? what is your research questions? what are your assumptions? Accurate in what sense? In coverage or something else? This Q is just too general, since as Dave said, these methods address different problems. I am sure Efron knows more about bootstrap than I do (or more than anybody), but that statement is only true about some models, not others (I think).

Comment: I have further updated the question regarding assumptions and definition of accurate @rep_ho